# unable to import jquery dependencies in vue-browerify template

Tags: jquery, dependencies, browserify, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using vue js [browerify](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/browserify) and i have installed `jquery`

i am using jquery as `import $ from 'jquery` and  it works.
To import anyother dependency like `semantic.js` or `jquery.ui` is it throwing errors.
I have read and tried all the related posts on stackoverflow.

when i do
`import $ from 'jquery`
`import 'jquery-ui`

it says jQuery in not defined.

i have tried the `extend` method. it still does not work.
I also have tried to include the files on my `index.html` usng the `<Script src>` tag . and it says `$` not defined.

please help.

Comment: Can you give us a code example and error message so we can understand your problem?

Answer (score 0):

When using jQuery as es6 module `window.jQuery` won't be available to other libraries requiring `window.jQuery` to be set, you need to define it yourself:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
window.$ = window.jQuery = $

import 'jquery-ui'
import '...'
```

Comment: yes, i had tried this also. didn't work.
i call the code inside `mounted`