# how to call a method of another component

Tags: vuejs2, browserify, vue-component

I migrated my application from `VueJs` to `Vue2` using the browserify template.

I have two components:

- Menu

  ```
  export default {
  name: 'Menu',
  data:function(){
   return{
    menu: []
  }, 
  events:{
     'set-menu':function(){ this.setMenu()},
  methods:{
     setMenu(){
         this.menu =  ['home']
  },
  ```

  }
- Login

  ```
  import Menu from './Menu.vue'
  exports default {
     ..... // code here
      // i want to trigger Menu.setMenu here
  }
  ```

i have tried:

- `Menu.methods.setMenu()` but the value of this is not as expected.
- `Menu.methods.setMenu.call(app)` where window.app is the new Vue in app.js
- `Menu.methods.setMenu.call(new Vue())`
- `app.$emit('setmenu')`

nothing seems to work here.

in Vue1 `this.$parent.$children[1].setMenu()` used to work perfectly. how to achieve that now

Comment: Since you have a login component it seems that your app maybe below medium to medium sized app.

Its better you start using vuex(https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html). If you want how its done with vuex I can post example snippet in answer

Comment: Using this.$parent is not much recommended by vue . See here(https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#parent)

Comment: @user7814783 can vueX be used with vue2-browserify or does it require complete migration. no i am **not** using parent. i am asking an alternative.

Comment: nope vuex can be used with vue2, browserify, its pretty simple process for the integration

Comment: @user7814783 do you deeper explaining link? or a sample working code.

Comment: vuex official docs are good enough for complete understanding of how to have centralized state management. Or for real world example you can refer to https://coligo.io/learn-vuex-by-building-notes-app/. Even the github page of vuex has real world examples here(https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples). If any futher doubts you can reply me at stack overflow.

Comment: @user7814783 in my case, can i just put the `setMenu` as a vuex action and leave the rest of the application as it is?   will it work?

Comment: yup it will work, but why only that one methid try moving all you state management code into vuex

Comment: @user7814783 how to execute the `actions` from inside a method of a component. it says this.setMenu is not a function

Comment: inside the method of the component you can execute (correctly speaking dispatching) your action using   this.$store.dispatch('your_action_name')

Comment: thanks a LOT. works perfectly. was banging my head for 2 days on it :) thank you so much

Comment: no probs ! Would assist if any further help required

Comment: @user7814783 completely off topic but could u answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677351/unable-to-import-jquery-dependencies-in-vue-browerify-template question also ?